# How to get y-axis boundary line using highchart?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am trying to get y axis to show up in highchart

[image]

I can use `x-axis` `plotline` to simulate the result, but it has the x-axis protruding over the `y-axis`

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickLength: 0,
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#000000',
            width: 1,
            value: 1370131200000
        }]
    },
```

Note: `1370131200000` is the lowest x value in my series.

Can someone let me know how do I define `y-axis` properly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `yAxis.lineWidth` property. By default it equals to `0` and that's why the line is not visible.

**API reference:**
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.lineWidth